# Writing and Reading an NFC Tag on Windows and Android Devices

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I am writing the following in an NFC tag to be able to open my app:

#### Uri = "nameofmyapp://parameterformyapp"

This works fine when I tap the tag using a windows 8 phone. If I have installed the app on my phone, the apps opens. If not, it searches for it at the store.

I would like to do exactly the same thing when the tag is tapped using an Android phone. Right now, neither it opens the app if the app is installed in the android device, and neither tries to search for it in the store, if the app is not installed. I suppose I have a syntax error somewhere :(. I have been doing several reading but couldn't find any sample that I could try. Does anyone has an idea on how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue you are looking for is the AAR ([Android Application Record](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar)). This is an additional NDEF record on a tag, which launches the specific application (in [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android)) or downloads it from the market (play store) if not available on the android device.